# Android Web View not able to view PDF From Amazon Service Url

Tags: android, pdf, amazon-web-services, webview

I am trying to display pdf file in android webview by calling amazon url. But it only shows white screen.Nothing to load.

When i use url other then amazon it shows pdf file in webview.
I have also tried this:
**http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + MYURL**

I have also tried under write url as well: And works well.
http://www.durgasoft.com/Android%20Interview%20Questions.pdf

If any one have any suggestion please guide me.

Here is my code for your reference:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
 String url = Common.getPdfFromAmazon("52f3761d290c4.pdf");   
 webView.loadUrl(url);

Android Menifest.xml also give Internet Permission:
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />**

i can also try this "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url ;
```

[image: Here is my logcat image.]

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your stacktrace ?

Comment: It doesn't shown any error or warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 2 day research no solution find for that so i try to first download PDF file from Amazon web service and store into the SD-Card then open PDF File Here My Code

Note:- **This solution is only try for  Show PDF in Web view From Amazon web Service.
from other web service try this Code:-**

```
   WebView webview=(WebView)findviewbyid(R.id.Webview);
   String MyURL= "this is your PDF URL";
   String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + MyURL;
   Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
   webView.loadUrl(url);
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------> For Amazon Web Service Please Try This code

```
   1>> Download PDF from Amazon WebService

public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.connect();

        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

2>> Show PDF From SD-Card

```
public static  void showPdfFromSdCard(Context ctx)
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/MyPdf.pdf");
    PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
         ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, 
            "No Application Available to View PDF", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

After Download PDF showPdfFromSdCard Method called.

After show PDF you Delete PDF file From SD-card
  Here Code for Delete PDF From SD-Card

```
public static void deletePdfFromSdcard(){
    File file = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/MyPdf.pdf");
    boolean pdfDelete = file.delete();


}
```

Comment: I want to open that downloaded file(location is download folder) in to webview.
is it possible? if yes  please share

Comment: Is there any solution that preview s3 url without downloading pdf?

Answer (score 5):

For displaying a PDF from amazon web service you need to first download and store the PDF to your device and then open it through PDF reader/viewer application available on your device.

1>> Call `DownloadFileAsync()` to invoke download process and pass your amazon web service url.

```
new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
```

2>> Do the download PDF process in AsyncTask.

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... aurl) {

        try {
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File dir = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
            if(dir.exists()==false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File directory = new File(dir, "original.pdf");
            try {
                if(!directory.exists())
                    directory.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            conexion.connect();
            conexion.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conexion.setConnectTimeout(15000); // millis

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);

            InputStream in = conexion.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.flush();
            f.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    }
}
```

3>> Call `showPdfFromSdCard()` after downloading pdf.

```
public static  void showPdfFromSdCard(Context ctx) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pdf/original.pdf");
    PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,
                "No Application Available to View PDF",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

4>> Call `deletePdfFromSdcard()` in your `onResume()`

```
public static void deletePdfFromSdcard(){
    File file = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/original.pdf");
    boolean pdfDelete = file.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the internet permission to your manifest file outside of the application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: if u have any other idea for that please help me.

Comment: Unless you have a error message, or an error from the stack trace i can't help much...

Answer (score 0):

```
I will do some modification in @Monika Moon code,

if you don't want to save the File in the device, the process explained above is too long as well as required FileProvider to open the pdf in external pdf viewer.

so for the better solution please follow the below steps.
Step 1:
```

please add this library to your gradle file.
[AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

```
Step 2:

add this in your XML view->

   <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Step 3:

PDFView pdfView;

InputStream inputStream;

pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

```
        class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (mProgressDialog!=null)
            {
                Utils.cancelProgressDialog(mProgressDialog);
            }
            mProgressDialog = Utils.showProgressDialog(DocumentViewActivity.this);

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(final String... aurl) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                conexion.setReadTimeout(20000);
                conexion.setConnectTimeout(25000); // millis


                 inputStream = conexion.getInputStream();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {


            if (inputStream != null) {
                pdfView.fromStream(inputStream)
                        .defaultPage(0)
                        .password(null)
                        .scrollHandle(null)
                        .enableAntialiasing(true)
                        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(DocumentViewActivity.this))
                        .spacing(0)
                        .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                                Utils.cancelProgressDialog(mProgressDialog);

                            }
                        })
                        .load();
            }else {
                Utils.cancelProgressDialog(mProgressDialog);
            }
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (inputStream!=null)
    {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Final Step : call `new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);`

Answer (score 0):

I might be late here but check once that url is working or not on browser.

Also try to encode it before loading to webView.

Signed/Signature url also worked.

```
documentURL = URLEncoder.encode(documentURL);
if (isDocument) {
    finalUrl = "https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + documentURL
    // below method is to open pdf with web view
    displayPdfWithWebView(finalUrl);
}
```